# Qt: check if a file in folder is changed

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, qfile, qfilesystemwatcher

There any way to trigger an action if a file in a specified directory ( or in a subfolder ) without fetching all modification times every time ? I'm asking because i've to check this live

Comment: well this solved my problem as well, grateful to the SO platform.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the QFileSystemWatcher.

More importantly, this is the signal you need to connect to:

> [void QFileSystemWatcher::fileChanged(const QString & path) [signal]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html#fileChanged)
>
> This signal is emitted when the file at the specified path is modified, renamed or removed from disk.
>
> See also directoryChanged().

So, you could write something like this in your class or function:

```
...
QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
watcher.addPath("/My/Path/To/The/File");

QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString&)), receiver, SLOT(handleFileChanged(const QString&)));
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [QFileSystemWatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html).